# Can I do multi master replication for Mongo DB? Any reference architecture with Kubernetes is more expected in this question

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, database-replication

I have a use case where we have a write and read intensive application using the MongoDB in backend. We are planning to implement federated K8s deployment for the Mongo DB with multi master architecture(How to do this?). I am looking for some suggestions on the architecture references/solutions if any that REALLY worked with Federation and active DB replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer you question but I know Kubedb does provide extensive database deployments within K8S. https://kubedb.com/docs/0.9.0/guides/mongodb/